# Django reply to comment in ajax does not work

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I am writing an application in django 2.2 with ajax. It's about the comments section and responses to comments. I have two problems:

1. Writing a new comment works. The response to the comment does not work, an error appears: `The view spot.views.SpotDetailView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`
2. Validation - if a comment is added, it works, but the error appears on all windows to respond to comments. The validation of the response to the comment does not work, the page source appears instead of the error

view.py

```
class SpotDetail(DetailView):
    model = Spot
    context_object_name = 'spot'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CommentModelForm()
        return context


class SpotDetailView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = SpotDetail.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = SpotComment.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

class SpotComment(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'spot/spot_detail.html'
    form_class = CommentModelForm
    model = Spot

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('spot_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug, 'id': self.object.pk})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        form.instance.spot = self.object
        form.instance.author = self.request.user

        if form.is_valid():
            reply = request.POST.get('comment_id')
            comment_qs = None
            if reply:
                comment_qs = Comment.objects.get(id=reply)
                form.instance.reply = comment_qs
            form.save()

            if request.is_ajax():
                context = {
                    'form': form,
                    'errors': form.errors,
                    'object': self.object,
                }
                html = render_to_string('spot/comments.html', context, request=request)
                return JsonResponse({'form': html})
        else:
            context = {
                'form': form,
                'errors': form.errors,
                'object': self.object,
            }
            html = render_to_string('spot/comments.html', context, request=request)
            return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.comment-form', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var serialized = $('.comment-form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: serialized,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            $('.comment-section').html(response['form']);
            $('textarea').val('');
            $('.reply-btn').click(function(){
                $('.replied-comment').fadeToggle();
                $('textarea').val('');
            });
        },
        error: function(rs, e){
            console.log(rs.responseText);
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('submit', 'form[id^="reply-comment-"]', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var pk = $(form[id^="reply-comment-"]).attr('value');
    var serialized = $('#reply-form' + pk).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: serialized,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            $('.comment-section').html(response['form']);
            $('textarea').val('');
            $('#reply-comment-btn-' + pk).click(function(){
                $('.replied-comment').fadeToggle();
                $('textarea').val('');
            });
        },
        error: function(rs, e){
            console.log(rs);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You added code for `SpotComment` while the error shown is at `SpotDetailView`. Please add that code too.

Comment: @RiteshAgrawal I added SpotDetail view, pls check

Comment: you added `SpotDetail`. While the error is in `SpotDetailView`.

Comment: @RiteshAgrawal you had right, sorry, now is `SpotDetailView`.

Comment: Try using the print statement for the `SpotComment` view. Check if it is reaching that view. If yes, then check for `request.is_ajax` return value. If your function does not go in that if condition then it will return `None`. Which could be one of the issue.

Comment: @RiteshAgrawal it is reaching `SpotComment` but there is no value for `request.is_ajax`

Comment: print value of `request.is_ajax` in `SpotDetailView` once. 
`is_ajax` code `self.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'`
Check for `Meta` values in request.